# Using jQuery AJAX call to pass a variable and start a PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a form on my website and if it fails validation (It is set to only accept some email TLDs) I want to save the email address into a .txt file.

To do this I want to include an AJAX call to pass the email address as a variable and call a PHP function, which writes the email address to a file.

It doesn't work and I can't understand why. I've hooked my function to the built in Wordpress AJAX handler. Any thoughts much appreciated.

---- EDIT: This now works -----

PHP

```
function text_ajax_process_request() {
    // first check if data is being sent and that it is the data we want
    if ( isset( $_POST["post_var"] ) ) {
        // now set our response var equal to that of the POST var (this will need to be sanitized based on what you're doing with with it)
        $response = $_POST["post_var"];
        file_put_contents('/home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/' . "login-error.txt", $response . ', ', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        echo $response;
    die();
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_response', 'text_ajax_process_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_test_response', 'text_ajax_process_request');
```

This is the jQuery Function

```
function newbie(email) {
var data = {
action: 'test_response',
                        post_var: email
                        };

// This is a shortened version of: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
    jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data, 
    function(response) {
        alert(response);
            });
        return false;
}
```

And this is the jQuery used to call it

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var email = 'enter email here';
        newbie(email);
        });
```

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser and look in the network tab to find out if the ajax is fired and what the response is. It will help find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @rolandstarke. Looking at that, the AJAX is fired but the response is 0. Any thoughts?

Comment: @LinzDarlington Where is your PHP code? In `functions.php`?

Comment: It's in a separate plugin file. Should amount to the same though. I'll try it in functions PHP.

Comment: The reason I ask is because typically a `0` response means the action isn't set (which it **is** in your example) or the callback function `write_to_file` isn't available at the time the AJAX call is made.

Comment: Thanks @JaredCobb. I think I've got it on the run and will report shortly.